# Use of Listview.builder makes the screen go away

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to show **Listview** underneath my two widgets but when i hot reload, nothing happens and if i run again, UI shows blank screen. If i remove **Listview.builder** it works fine.

Below is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plant_clone/constants.dart';
import 'package:plant_clone/model/model.dart';
import 'package:plant_clone/screens/home/components/header_with_searchbox.dart';
import 'package:plant_clone/screens/home/components/title_with_more_btn.dart';
import 'package:plant_clone/viewmodel/recommended_plants_viewmodel.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  RecommendedPlantViewModel recommendedPlantViewModel =
      new RecommendedPlantViewModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    recommendedPlantViewModel.setWidgetsData();
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          HeaderWithSearchBox(size: size),
          TitleWithMoreButton(
            title: "Recommended",
            press: () {},
          ),
          ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: (){},
                    title: Text('Hello'),
                  ),
                );
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `build` method will be called multiple times. it means you are calling `recommendedPlantViewModel.setWidgetsData();` multiple times as well. You should never do anything other than drawing widgets inside build method.

Comment: @user6327816 You don't know what that method does. It may be updating/retrieving data synchronously that is used within the OP's widgets.

Comment: Wrap the list in a flexible or expanded widget.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore you are right. But the name suggests it's a viewmodel and there isn't any argument sent. So there is no use calling it from build method.

Comment: Is there any error or warnings in logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's any other way than setting height constraint using a `SizedBox` that's wrapping a `ListView`.

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: size.height,
      child: ListView.builder(
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list

Comment: the listview used here is Horizontal with Column as parent.

Comment: I've totally missed that. Thanks for noticing! @user6327816

Answer (score 1):

i think it happened because the list view should have a height,,
the esiest way is to test that put it inside a container and give a height to it..
and the second way is wrap the listview inside a Expanded widget and it will fix ..
if not then post the error from debug log

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this to work, you must wrap your ListView with a Container and define the height property as it is part of a Column. You also need to wrap the widget returned by the itemBuilder with a Container and define the width property as the scrollDirection is set to Axis.horizontal.

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: 3,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        width: 100,
        child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            title: Text('Hello'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```